# Is there any way to use an external private maven repository like S3 Bucket in AWS Code Build plan instead of using the default central maven repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create an AWS code build project to build my project linking to AWS code commit, but I would replace the default central maven repository with my private repo on S3 Bucket. I wouldn't like to modify pom.xml, and instead want to config the AWS Build plan to fetch the dependencies from my S3 Bucket.